# Can the node.js nano@6.2.0 connect with TLS 1.2+ to the Cloudant database?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red, cloudant

We'd like to confirm if the nano@6.2.0 can connect with TLS 1.2+ to the Cloudant database even after June 1, 2019.

As per the IBM Cloudant announcement: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/announcements/ibm-cloudant-security-update-tls-1-2-and-service-endpoints, starting on June 1, 2019, the IBM Cloudant API will require Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.2 and above. The IBM Cloudant API requires HTTPS and currently supports TLS 1.0 and above.

IBM Cloud Node-Red Stater (Node.js  version: v8.15.1) uses nano@6.2.0 to connect to its backend Cloudant database to manage the Node-Red Flow.
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano/v/6.2.0

```
.../nodered-starter../blob/master/index.js
Line 36: storage.init(settings)....
.../nodered-starter../blob/master/couchstorage.js
Line 73-76:
var couchstorage = {
    init: function(_settings) {
        settings = _settings;
        var couchDb = nano(settings.couchUrl);
...settings.couchUrl is like:
   https://username:password@abcd1234-bluemix.cloudant.com
```

About the IBM Cloud Node-Red Starter: https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/starters/node-red-starter

Comment: This is not a programming question, but rather a roadmap or confirmation question.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to [nodejs-cloudant](https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant/#tls-12-support) this will depend on the version of Node.js and OpenSSL installed. It is independent of the version of Apache CouchDB Nano.

OpenSSL has [supported TLSv1.2](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x35) since 1.0.1 in March 2012. From this [blog](https://developer.ibm.com/blogs/openssl-111-has-landed-in-nodejs-master-and-why-its-important-for-nodejs-lts-releases/) it appears the version of OpenSSL in Node.js 8.15.1 is 1.0.2r so it should work fine.